# Why is the scipy.stats.norm.ppf implementation so slow?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using scipy version 0.19.0. I see that under scipy\stats_continuous_distns , the function `_norm_ppf` wraps `scipy.special.ndtri`. My question is, what implementation is this using and why is it so slow?

For comparison, 
i created a c extension of a well known open-source implementation of inverse cdf within ASA 241 ("R8_NORMAL_01_CDF_INVERSE"). you can view it a version of it at this link: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/asa241/asa241.html

some naive benchmarking shows scipy's version to be almost 1000x slower:

```
import timeit
from scipy.stats import norm
from QSCoreExtensions import r8_normal_01_cdf_inverse # compiled extension

def a():
    norm.ppf(.3456)

def b():
    r8_normal_01_cdf_inverse(.3456)

print(timeit.timeit('a()', number=10000, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit('b()', number=10000, globals=globals()))
```

Output:

1.219758156838038

0.0021004953395136194

Note that any input (not just .3456) will yield similar results. Also, the r8_normal_01_cdf_inverse accuracy is 1 part in 10**16 which is actually more accurate than scipy.stats.norm.ppf

Comment: Would not this post be more useful at [SciPy issue tracker](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues)? Maybe there is no reason, and your approach should be used instead. Or there is, and some SciPy dev thought about it.

Comment: That software is distributed under the GNU LGPL license.  SciPy does not include GPL or LGPL code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also included the timing for `scipy.special.ndtri`.  `norm.ppf()` has additional overhead for argument validation and processing the `loc` and `scale` arguments.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser oh okay. Just for my understanding why doesn't scipy include GPL or LGPL?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser from my testing, the `scipy.special.ndtri` seems to be much faster than `scipy.stats.norm.ppf`. Could you please explain in more details why?

Comment: @MyWork, these comments are not the place for such a discussion.  My previous comment already mentions one reason; for more details, you could ask another question here on stackoverflow, or on the scipy-user mailing list.